# Function parameters check

Tags: function, powershell

I'm writing some basic powershell libraries, and I need to check if a specific parameter is in a group of values.

In this example I define a function ALV_time with an optional parameter. If defined, it could have only 2 values, else I signal a warning. It works, but is this the correct way to allow only some parameter values or is there a standard way?

```
$warningColor = @{"ForegroundColor" = "Red"}

function AVL_Time {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $format
    )

    process {
        # with format parameter
        if ($format) {
            # list format possible parameters
            $format_parameters = @("short: only date", "long: date and time")
            if ($format -like "short") {
                $now = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
            # long date
            elseif ($format -like "long") {
                $now = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
            # if wrong format parameter
            else {
                Write-Host @warningColor "Please use only those parameters:"
                $format_parameters | foreach {
                    Write-Host @warningColor "$_"
                }
            }
        }
        # without format parameter
        else {
            $now = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }

        # return time
        return $now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the check for you:

```
Param( 
        [ValidateSet("short","long")] 
        [String] 
        $format )
```

example script with more validations:

```
Function Foo 
{ 
    Param( 
        [ValidateSet("Tom","Dick","Jane")] 
        [String] 
        $Name 
    , 
        [ValidateRange(21,65)] 
        [Int] 
        $Age 
    , 
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Container'})] 
        [string] 
        $Path 
    ) 
    Process 
    { 
        "Foo $name $Age $path" 
    } 
}
```